# Tree Table Filters Sapui5

Tags: javascript, filter, sapui5, treetable

I have a problem with filtering rows in tree table, the normal table with same filters are working fine though.

Here is the normal table aggregation code:

```
tTotals.bindAggregation("rows",{
                    path: "totals>/prg_head",
                    filters: [
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("ID_PRG_VERSION", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, filterKRVR.program),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("ID_SCENARIO", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, filterKRVR.scenario),
                        new sap.ui.model.Filter("I_YEAR", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, filterKRVR.year)
                    ]}  
                );
```

And here is the tree table aggregation:

```
tEvents.bindAggregation("rows",{
                        path: "events>/prg_years(ID_SCENARIO=" + filterKRVR.scenario + ",I_YEAR=" + filterKRVR.year + "m)" + "/HisGTO",
                        filters: [
                            new sap.ui.model.Filter("ACTION_AMOUNT", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.NE, 0)
                        ],
                        parameters: {
                            navigation: {
                                'prg_gto':  "HisPIPE",
                                'prg_pipe': "HisKS",
                                'prg_ks':   "HisLK"
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I even tried to write the filter inside the path of aggregation, tested it in xsodata link in this way, it worked, but from developer's tools I can see there is no filter applied to tEvents table, but for tTotals it's okay.
By the way, the model for these two aggregations is the same.
So how can I create a new filter for the tree table?

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Even I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @guitar_geek as far as i remember, in old versions of treetable, it cant filter data inside it, so i filtered the data from xsodata directly, by changing the path